# reading into pandas data frame excluding the first column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

while reading a text file to pandas data frames, what should I do to exclude the first column and read it

code currently using:

```
dframe_main =pd.read_table('/Users/ankit/Desktop/input.txt',sep =',')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would it suffice to just delete the column after you've read it in? This is functionally the same as excluding the first column from the read. Here's a toy example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [2,2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3,3], [4,4,3,4,4], [7,2,3,4,5]])
columns = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
dframe_main = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
print "All columns:"
print dframe_main
del dframe_main[dframe_main.columns[0]] # get rid of the first column
print "All columns except the first:"
print dframe_main
```

Output is:

```
All columns:
   one  two  three  four  five
0    1    2      3     4     5
1    2    2      2     2     2
2    3    3      3     3     3
3    4    4      3     4     4
4    5    2      3     4     5

All columns except the first:
   two  three  four  five
0    2      3     4     5
1    2      2     2     2
2    3      3     3     3
3    4      3     4     4
4    2      3     4     5
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use [usecols](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) parameter:

> **usecols** : array-like, default None Return a subset of the columns.
>
> Results in **much faster parsing time and lower memory usage.**

Assuming that your file has 5 columns:

```
In [32]: list(range(5))[1:]
Out[32]: [1, 2, 3, 4]

dframe_main = pd.read_table('/Users/ankit/Desktop/input.txt', usecols=list(range(5))[1:])
```